# error in importing sphinxbase and pocketsphinx in python 2.6.6

Tags: python, centos6, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am just installed Pocketsphinx and Sphinxbase and give all the related path accordingly::

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/

export PS_BASE=/usr/local

export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/

export PATH=$PATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PYTHONPATH

**pocketsphinx_continous** is working fine

but still while importing **sphinxbase** or **pocketsphinx** it shows error :

> > > import pocketsphinx
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named pocketsphinx

what else am i missing? Pls help me.

Comment: If it says no module it means there is no module. If you installed from source module must be in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages while you imported PYTHONPATH as /usr/lib without local. You need to review your exports. Also, you do not need to add PYTHONPATH AND LD_LIBRARY_PATH to PATH.

Comment: yes i have check every export , path is correct for python in my system it is in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/  but in that directory there is no module named sphinxbase and pocketsphinx ,how can i add modules in that directory

Comment: Modules are created when you make and install pocketsphinx, you can check the details in pocketsphinx build log.

Comment: i install pocketsphinx and sphinxbase in my system by:  ./configure , make , make install it creates some library file in /usr/local/lib but not in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/

Comment: Yes, this is expected. That's why you need to set PYTHONPATH to /usr/local/lib as I wrote before.